# Using probability of overlap to calculate number of particles

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a setup with multiple synchronized cameras recording an event with an unknown number $N$ particles. Only a subset of the particles are detected in any given camera, we assume an average of $n$ particles are detected in each camera. Of the $n$ particles detected in each camera, there is a certain number of particles $\eta$ that overlap in all cameras.

Based on the known values of $n$ and $\eta$, and assuming a uniformly distributed choice of particles $n$, it is possible to estimate the value of $N$ with

\begin{equation}
N=\left(\frac{n^c}{\eta}\right)^{\frac{1}{c-1}},
\end{equation}

where c is the number of cameras used.

I have derived this expression using very elementary probabilities and checked that it is correct with simple numerical experiments.

### Derivation

Let there be $N$ particles that are divided into group $\alpha$ with $n=rN$ particles, where $r=1/2$ is the find rate of each camera. A second group $\beta$ contains the other $n=rN$ particles. There are $c=3$ cameras imaging the particles and each camera will randomly sample $n=rN$ particles. For now let us assume that these will be either exactly group  $\alpha$ or group  $\beta$.

The probability of all three cameras imaging $\alpha$ is
\begin{equation}
P(A)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{8}  \,,
\end{equation}
and likewise the probability of all three cameras imaging $\beta$ is
\begin{equation}
P(B)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{8}  \,.
\end{equation}

The probability that all three camera image the same group (either all $\alpha$ or all $\beta$) is
\begin{equation}
P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)= \frac{1}{4}  \,.
\end{equation}
This means that there is a 1 out of 4 chance that all three cameras will image the same group of particles.

To generalize the statement, we remove the initial constraint of grouping particles into $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and allow any combination of particles $n$ in each camera. Now instead of having $r=1/2$ particles intersecting $P(A \cup B)= 1/4$ of the time, we can equivalently expect
\begin{equation}
R=r\,P(A \cup B)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{8}\,,
\end{equation}
of the particles intersecting all the time, where $R=\eta/N$ is the expected number of intersections as a ratio of $N$.

By examining this simple example, I can write a relationship for intersecting sets of random variables
\begin{equation}
\label{432}
R=r^c \,,
\end{equation}
where $\{r:\, 0\leq r\leq1\}$ is the find rate of each camera and $c$ is the number of cameras.

Substituting $R=\eta/N$ and $r=n/N$ into the above equation and solving for $N$ gives
\begin{equation}
N=\left(\frac{n^c}{\eta}\right)^{\frac{1}{c-1}}.
\end{equation}

### Question

I am not very satisfied with the way I derived my final equation. I need help coming up with a more mathematical approach to the derivation. I have tried with a Hypergeometric distribution, but could not extend that to beyond $c=2$.

As a next step I would like to derive a similar expression to solve for $N$ for the case where $n$ is no longer uniformly distributed over $N$, but rather distributed based on a known weighting function. I think if I get a good grasp on how to derive the original expression for $N$ mathematically, extending this to a weighted distribution should not be too difficult.

Comment: I would find it helpful if the title was more detailed.

Comment: This might also get more traction on https://stats.stackexchange.com